# How to meltdown multiple columns as rows in pyspark

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

I have a text file which is separated by a delimiter for every word. The text file is read using pyspark with spark.read.csv method with sep = "|". Based on this, the output returns 10 columns for eg as shown below.

```
c0  c1      c2     c3    c4     c5   c6      c7     c8    c9  
1   name1  add1   pr1   type1   2    name2   add2   pr2   type2
```

I need the output in terms of two rows as shown below.

```
c0  c1      c2     c3    c4  
1   name1  add1   pr1   type1
2   name2  add2   pr2   type2
```

Is there any methods from spark to meltdown the columns to rows as shown above?

Comment: this seems doable with a union -- using `unionAll()`

Comment: @samkart unionAll() or union() requires multiple dataframes. I am thinking not to split the existing dataframe into two dataframe and then union again.